# How to get each row and column..? from data column inside this we have jsonb format where all values are in sentences are to be breaked by each row

Tags: postgresql

How to achieve this in PostgreSQL database?

How to get each row and column? from data column inside this we have jsonb format where all values are in sentences are to be split by each row

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to store all fields and values (each by row) in JSON format. Do for this you can use `row_to_json` function. Example:

```
select t1.*, row_to_json(t1) as json_data from table1 t1;

Result: 
id      date            amount      json_data
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2       2021-01-24      10          {"id":2,"date":"2021-01-24","amount":10}
1       2021-02-06      30          {"id":1,"date":"2021-02-06","amount":30}
8       2021-02-06      30          {"id":8,"date":"2021-02-06","amount":30}
9       2021-02-06      30          {"id":9,"date":"2021-02-06","amount":30}
10      2021-02-06      30          {"id":10,"date":"2021-02-06","amount":30}
11      2021-02-06      30          {"id":11,"date":"2021-02-06","amount":30}
12      2021-02-06      30          {"id":12,"date":"2021-02-06","amount":30}
13      2021-02-06      30          {"id":13,"date":"2021-02-06","amount":30}
```